# Text in dynamically generated links appears after end tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am generating a link dynamically using jQuery by iterating some Json data.

**MyCode :**

```
var content = "<table>";
$.each(dataArray, function( index, value )
{
     content = content+"<tr><td>"+value.Version+"</td><td><a href="+value.Download+"> Download</a></td></tr>";
}); 
content = content+"</table>";
$('#tablediv').append(content);
```

It should generate a table with a link in 2nd colum as:

**< a href="link to url"> Download  < /a>**

But it generates it as :

**< a href="link to url">< /a> Download**

So I need text between start and end tag but it appears after end tag. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add single-quotes to your href attribute.

```
content += "<tr><td>"+value.Version+"</td><td><a href='"+value.Download+"'> Download</a></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `value.Download` in quotes:

```
"... <a href=\"" + value.Download + "\">Download</a> ...";
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var content = "<table>";
  var dataArray=[{Version:1,Download:"asdsa"},{Version:2,Download:"tete"}];
$.each(dataArray, function( index, value )
{
  var $row=$("<tr>");
  var $rowcellVersion= $("<td>").text(value.Version);
  var $rowcellContent= $("<td>");
  var $anchorTag = $("<a>").text("Download")
                           .attr("href",value.Download)  
                           .appendTo($rowcellContent);
  
  $rowcellVersion.appendTo($row);
  $rowcellContent.appendTo($row);
  
  content = content + $row[0].outerHTML;
  
}); 
content = content+"</table>";
$('#tablediv').append(content);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tablediv"></div>
```

A bit cleaner way of handling the creation of elements .Also you can check the HTML in page inspector .It's the expected way

Comment: this is a very expensive way to perform such a simple task

Comment: yeah it can be but for easy understanding , i kept the variables as such. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage jQuery if you are using it in a first place

```
var content = $("<table>");
$.each(dataArray, function( index, value )
{
  content.append($("<tr />")
     .append($("<td />").text(value.Version))
     .append($("<td />").append(
              $("<a />").attr("href",value.Download).text(value.Version))
);
$('#tablediv').append(content);
```